# swiper js not working for repeat component in pages

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I used from swiper js in my project. I added in index.html header:

```
<script src="./assets/js/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

One of the components related to `products similar` to my application are repeated in many different parts. But my problem is that only the component at the top of the main page of my site works and the other components do not work.

[my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ8C0.png)

Comment: How’re you initializing each instance? Note that the `new swiper()` call only accepts a single HTMLElement or a class selector, which will select the first occurring element that matches it. You will need to loop through the node list of all elements that matches a class if you’re using the latter.

Comment: unknown this code in my `.ts` file:
`var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper

// Now you can use all slider methods like
mySwiper.slideNext();`

Comment: Yup that’s the problem. It only selects the first instance. That’s why all your other elements don’t work.

Comment: How can I enable the sliders?